# How to return File Path in Html of Gulp s3 Upload?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, gulp

I'm creating an image optimiser using gulp and PHP for the Upload.

I want to be able to output the file path url of the uploaded file into index.php what is the best way to do it..

i've tried mimicking the output of the file path using the below, but didn't work..
 -:   print 'https://footpatrol.s3.amazonaws.com/images/'.date('Y').'/'. date('d-m').'/'.$newfilename.'';

PHP Code.

```
<?php
$files = glob('images/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
          foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $index=>$name){

             $filename = $name;

             if(!file_exists("images/".$filename)){
                $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
                $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
                $newfilename = md5($file_basename) . $file_ext;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$index],"images/" . $newfilename);

                    if(     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$index],"images/" . $newfilename)){
            print '<div class="img">https://footpatrol.s3.amazonaws.com/images/'.date('Y').'/'. date('d-m').'/'.$newfilename.'</div>';
          }

              }

          } 
?>
```

Gulp Code..

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var s3 = require('gulp-s3');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs')
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var jpegrecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress');
var moment = require('moment');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

// Delete files in image folder
gulp.task('cleanTemp', function(cb) {
    return gulp.src('dist/images/*', { read: false }).pipe(clean());
    cb(err)
});

// Delete files in image folder
gulp.task('delete', ['image'], function() {
    return gulp.src('./images/*', { read: false })
        .pipe(clean());
});


var year = moment().format('YYYY');
var today = moment().format('MM-DD');
// // Image Optimisation
//console.log('dist/images/'+year+'/'+today)
gulp.task('image',['cleanTemp'], function() {
    return gulp.src('images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
            jpegrecompress({
                progressive: true,
                max: 70,
                min: 55
            }),
            pngquant({ quality: '70-80' })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images/' + year + '/' + today + ''));
});


aws = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./aws.json'));


// // UPLOAD
gulp.task('upload', function() {
    return gulp.src('./dist/**')
        .pipe(s3(aws))
});
// Watch Image files
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('images/*', function(event) {
        runSequence('cleanTemp', ['image','upload']);
    });
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['cleanTemp','image', 'upload']);
```